# Does the Normalizer of a Group Contain Itself?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $G$ is a group, and $A$ is a subgroup of $G$. I would like to know if the normalizer of $A$ in $G$ $N_G(A)$ contains $A$ itself. My reasoning is that for all $a\in A$, $aAa^{-1}\subset A$. And in particular, $e\in A$, and $eAe^{-1}= A$. Is this a correct claim?

Comment: Yes, though you did not really need to check for $e$, since $e\in A$ already.